# Get user id in Laravel Gate

Tags: laravel

I have done a lot of research but can not understand how to obtain the user id(not parent's id). I have the parent and the user, the parent is who manages the user.

A parent is an online user.

I need to check if the edited user has a balance.

@can('can-device', dd($user->id)) // return user id

//Gate

```
Gate::define('can-device', function (User $user) {
    dd(user->id) //return parent id
    return $user->hasBalance();
});


    // User model
    @property int $id
 * @property integer $parent_id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $role
 * @property string $status
 * @property integer $balance
 * @property float $discount


public function hasBalance(): bool
{
    return $this->balance !== 0;
} 

 public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(static::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(static::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}


@can('can-device', $user)
<a href="{{ route('admin.devices.create', ['userId' => $user]) }}"
```

How can I obtain the user id?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It seems like you need to include some more code to explain how you are doing the parent user logic, as this is not standard by Laravel. When you call @can('can-device', $user) is it in context of a user or parent?

Comment: I just updated my question. Basically, I only want to know if a user has a balance.

Comment: Does not answer the question about parent id and user_id, you will have the id of the user you pass to the gate?

Comment: This is my problem, in the gate I only have parent_id, I need user_id.

Comment: Tbh you clearly do not understand, your question is very simple but no one understands your domain else there would have been an answer by now, what is a parent_id in comparasion to an user_id? This is not standard laravel feature.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself well. The parent has many children. So in my case, parent_id is the user online, and the user_id is the child.

Comment: How does your user model look like?

Comment: I just updated the question with the User model.

Comment: But one user can have multiple childs, should you check the balance of all of them?

Comment: Of course, I need to check the balance of every children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `Laravel` collection function every, where all element of a collection has to be true to a given condition, for syntactic sugar, i use a higher order function call. While getting the children as a eloquent collection with `->children`.

```
Gate::define('can-device', function (User $user) {
    return $user->hasBalance() && $user->children->every->hasBalance();
});
```

**EDIT**

You can utilize filter to only get users with a balance.

```
$user->children->filter('balance')->every->hasBalance()
```

Comment: ok, this works if all the children have a balance, but as there are some child without balance it does not work anymore, is possible to check for every child

This works

@if($user->hasBalance())
    <a href="{{ route('admin.devices.create', ['userId' => $user]) }}"
     ....
@endif

Is it possible to do the same with the gate?

Comment: Thank you very much.